# How to resolve memory allocation error in OpenCart?

Tags: php, opencart, dynamic-memory-allocation

Below error appears in OpenCart:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 2097152 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 8192 bytes)
```

File: \system\storage\vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Extension\Core.php on line 149

I do not understand what does this mean, because memory being allocated is smaller than the allowed size. And how do I resolve it?

Comment: It means your code tried to use _another_ 8192 byes, exceeding the limit. Not 8192 bytes for the whole request

Comment: See [`memory_limit`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit).

Comment: in your php.ini increase `memory_limit = 512M;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit php.ini file from opencart folder and increase the size of "memory_limit" until error not gone

```
memory_limit = 128M;
```

**OR**

Edit "config.php" and "admin/config.php" add below code at the end

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '128M');
```